# Only allow to accept/reject edits if you have a high score in the question's tags (also for answers)

Tags: feature-request, rejected-edits

I recently suggested a very basic edit. It was just moving something that was inside a function and shouldn't be there outside of it. Everyone familiar with the term refactoring knows that this can look like a big change but in reality it was just one single step (actually it wasn't even just refactoring in this case it was correcting a bug). Looking at the users rejecting the edits I saw that two of them seemed to have low to no experience in this programming language and one of them had it as 2nd tag, but with a big offset to the first.

Couldn't you make it dependent on the user's tags instead of just the reputation over all?

I realize it's not easy, because some tags are very frequent and others are not. But I'm sure we could come up with a decent formula.

Comment: Suggested code edits are (and should be) treated with the utmost caution. If you do not have sufficient rep to just edit posts then you should refrain from suggesting code edits unless the code is fundamentally broken (and that wasn't the cause of the question), there is a basic typo the author missed, or you are taking care of formatting issues.

Comment: @slugster, see my answer below - the FAQ suggests that even typos don't warrant editing code. As the FAQ reads, you should very, very rarely actually ***change*** code, but rather edit code typically only for formatting concerns.

Comment: Although that's only for questions - the guidelines for editing answers seem to be looser.

Comment: @sphanley should I delete my question or leave for others even if low rating?

Comment: @maraca Leave it - the low rating doesn't cost you anything, and it shows future viewers that this option has already been considered and/or answered. The down votes are because people disagree with the idea rather than because it's a bad question.

Comment: @sphanley thanks again, that was solved very quickly

Comment: @maraca, I'm glad you feel the answer helped. And again, to confirm what was already said - reputation doesn't work the same way on Meta as the rest of the site, and especially so on posts tagged [feature-request]. On feature request posts, it typically means whether people endorse or reject the feature being requested, not that they think the post is "bad".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the FAQ post on [when edits to code are appropriate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code), you'll see that it declares you should **not** edit code even to do things like:

> - Fix Syntax (non-closed brackets, missing semi-colons, etc.)
> - Fix typos (misspelled function calls, variable names, etc.)

Those cases are likely even more clear-cut then making the determination that something "should be" outside a function, so if you feel that a code change of that nature ought to be made, it's more appropriate to leave a comment suggesting it, or if the change is significant enough to warrant doing so, post an entirely new answer about it.

Comment: Ok thank you, it is just frustrating to see wrong code in the answers. It might work correct in 99% of the cases but still fail in 1%

Comment: That's totally understandable - but if you point out incorrect code in an answer, there's a decent chance that the answerer will fix it. And if you've accumulated enough rep to have your edits no longer "suggested", as noted in the comments above, then you don't have to worry about approval (although you should still be very, very sure that your edit is warranted before changing other poster's code).

Comment: @maraca Once you have sufficient rep you can edit it into shape. Otherwise before then consider down voting (if it is a severe enough issue) or leave a comment.

Comment: You're quoting the section on editing code in *questions*, not *answers*.  The OP here was editing an *answer*.  The edit was wrong, but not for that reason.  It also doesn't apply; he wasn't fixing either a typo or a syntax error.

Comment: @Servy, yeah, I realized that once the OP elaborated in comments, but the orignal question doesn't seem to specify what's being edited. And I know that the edit in question doesn't fall into the types quoted, but my point was that those types, which are prohibited by the FAQ, are likely even less subjective than what the OP was describing.

Comment: @sphanley I link to the suggested edit in my answer.  Someone used a random number generator in a local in an answer, and the OP moved it to be a static field so as to prevent it from being re-created with the same seed if the method is called repeatedly.  It's such a radically different situation from what you're explaining here that it's rather misleading.

Comment: @servy Fair enough. I'd have understood the situation better if OP had linked to the actual edit in question to begin with. I'd delete this answer were it not accepted. maraca, Servy's answer does a much better job of covering your specific case.

Comment: @Servy I didn't wanna expose anybody, but in this case it is really a mistake, executed twice in the same millisecond will give the same result instead of random (so not only performance). All my other edits were accepted, so it is a rare case... I have no intention to go hunting for mistakes

Comment: @sphanley your answer is the best. Sevy's answer doesn't do a better job, what he did there is just wrong. Even if it looks easier. For so many reasons. Debugging, performance and most important it is buggy. I think code should be presented like it is best practice.

Comment: @maraca As I have told you, it doesn't *matter* that the answer was wrong.  Edits are not there to change wrong answers into correct answers when you disagree with how a problem should be solved.  The fact that you don't like that policy doesn't change the fact that *that is the stated policy*.  The fact that you like this answer more doesn't change the fact that it is completely incorrect in it's explanation of what the site's policies are with respect to this situation.

Comment: @Servy as already mentioned I don't argue about that. I just have a problem with your answer because if I read it it sounds like my suggestion is wrong, but it is correct, it was just the wrong way to do it.

Comment: @maraca My answer states that it's improper of you to make the edit, regardless of which answer is better based on technical merit, which is exactly what SE's policy is on editing.  If you assume I was making a judgement about the edit's technical merit, then that's simply not the case at all.  The whole *point* of the answer is that it's *irrelevant*.

Comment: @Servy then why is there a need to link to the answer, it looks like this is a specific case, but it is really a generalized suggestion. The 2nd sentence covers everything.

Comment: @maraca It's really both.  You spend the majority of your question explaining why the improper action was taken on your suggested edit, and then propose a change to prevent that improper action from being taken.  The fact that the correct action was actually taken (as the edit should have been rejected) is very much relevant, as you have now lost your example demonstrating why your change is needed.

Answer (score 3):

Questions are often inappropriately tagged. Giving permissions depending on it would be an unreliable system. Also, tags can be edited (removed, changed, etc.). That makes your proposal not work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using suggested edits to change an answer from what the author intended to something that you think is just "better".  If there was a simple typo in the code in which the OP, say, clearly meant to refer to a particular variable or method but just spelled it wrong, or was missing a parenthesis/bracket that they clearly intended to be there, then fixing those mistakes is perfectly fine *in an answer*.  (You should not be fixing those types of issues in code in a question, as you may be removing the problem at the heart of the question.)

[In your case](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7730911), however, the OP wrote out exactly what they intended to have the code do, you simply disagreed with them over what the proper way to solve that problem.  In such a case it is *very* in appropriate to simply edit someone else's answer to be in line with what you think it should be, contrary to their intentions.  You can post your own answer if you have an alternate solution to the problem and/or comment on the post asking the author to change it.

As for your actual proposal, very few suggested edits actually require any knowledge of the subject matter to evaluate.  There are some that come up, every now and again (yours is arguably an example of one, but it was *correctly rejected* whereas someone without any knowledge of the subject may or may not have known that they should reject the edit).

Comment: I first explained to you what is the mistake, but you disagreed. AFTER that I suggested the edit which is REQUIRED or do you think it is better to have WRONG code there just because it is a little simpler. Also when you want to debug and set the seed determent your implementation won't work, performance is worse... and and and

Comment: If you tell me I have a bug and show me why I will correct it... unlike others

Comment: Bottom line... I don't THINK it's better, it is correct opposed to your wrong answer. This whole answer makes me angry. Just admit your mistakes and don't point back at me.

Comment: @maraca It doesn't *matter* whether you're right or not.  If you see an answer that's wrong its *improper* to edit the answer to change it.  You can downvote it, comment, and/or post your own answer that is correct.  Edits are there to improve the presentation of an existing answer, not to change the answer's solution.

Comment: Yes, that I understood now. So there was no need for your answer here. Next time I won't do it.

Comment: But you *didn't* understand that, so there *was* a need for this answer.  The fact that you now know this to be true *because I have told you as much in my answer* means that there *was* a need for it.

Comment: no sphanley explained it to me yesterday

Comment: @maraca He stated that edits should not be used to fix typos or syntax errors in answers.  This is both incorrect (edits *can* be used to fix syntax errors or typos in code in answers, just not in questions, and this case doesn't involve a question) and also irrelevant, because your situation involves neither a syntax error or a typo, but rather simply an answer that the author thinks is right, and that you think is wrong.

Comment: I would agree if it wasnt for the last sentence. You still don't get it, I don't thinkk it is wrong. It is wrong. Period. An implementation that only works under some conditions is  a faulty implementation. Because of mistakes like this space rockets crash.

Comment: @maraca It doesn't *matter* whether you're correct or not.  I've said this like half a dozen times.  If you think the answer is incorrect, downvote, comment, and or post a better one.  Editing the answer to be what you think it should be is *not appropriate*.  Whether your solution is better or not *doesn't matter*.  It's wrong to make the change *even if you are correct*, so saying that you're correct *changes nothing*.  What about this is so hard to understand?

Comment: Nothing, you just seem to have a problem choosing the right words. Everything was good until  "... and what you think is wrong." I wouldn't suggest if if I wasn't 100% sure. "... and what you know is wrong" would be acceptable.

Comment: @maraca The whole *point* is that I am making no judgement whatsoever about whether or not you are correct in your assertions because **it doesn't matter whether or not you are correct**.  So you're saying that the correct answer to your question is wrong purely because I didn't state that you were absolutely and unquestionably correct about something that is *completely irrelevant*.  You're trying to say that for my 100% correct answer to be "acceptable" I need to praise you about something 100% irrelevant to the question at hand?  Are you serious?

Comment: No, you try to make me sound stupid by repeating your stuff over and over again like I always say the same thing. Your language just tells me that you still think your answer is right. I know it doesn't matter for the suggestion here. But I would just correct the mistake instead of making a big fuss about it. You just don't get the impact that such mistakes can have.

Comment: You have stated that my answer is right, you just don't like it because you think I may possible have conceivably have insinuated that you aren't perfect.  If you don't want to "make a big fuss about it" then why did you create a meta post *specifically to discuss the issue?  What indication do you have that I don't understand the impact of these types of mistakes?  All I'm telling you is that *you're going about dealing with it the wrong way*.  I'm not saying that it isn't a mistake, I"m not saying you shouldn't deal with it, I"m saying that *edits aren't the right way to deal with it*.

Comment: That's the whole point. I was looking for a generalized solution. But usually if you want to improve something you have a reason for it. That's why I included that part. And how many times do I have to agree with you that it wasn't the correct way before you stop repeating it?

Comment: I've told you, many times, what to do in the general case.  When you see an answer that you think is wrong, do some combination of downvoting, commenting, and posting a better answer.  I'll stop repeating myself when you stop saying that my answer is wrong because of issues that are completely irrelevant to the question at hand.

Comment: Really interesting discussion technique you have here. Now that your previous argument didn't work any more you come with something new which I had never denied. Yes it doesn't matter for the suggestion if your answer is wrong. But you make it about that specific edit and your answer there is just wrong, if you like it or not. Have a nice day.

Comment: @maraca My answer *isn't* just about your specific edit.  It discusses it a fair bit, just as your question largely focuses on this one specific edit, but in addition to addressing the specific edit I also address your proposal, both in the context of the example given and in general.